# Can i convert a mysql field with invalid microseconds value to a datetime format?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, sql-update, date-format

I have a table imported from a csv file. However, the date field isn't not formatted nicely.

Is it possible to convert this string using a mysql **STR_TO_DATE** function?

I need this `'05/11/2009 16:07:53:052'` to be converted as a datetime format such like `'2009-05-11 16:07:53'` and ignoring the microsecs..

I tried using something like this

```
UPDATE mytable
SET updated_on = DATE(STR_TO_DATE(updated_on, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'))
```

And

```
UPDATE mytable
SET updated_on = DATE(STR_TO_DATE(updated_on, GET_FORMAT(DATETIME,'ISO')))
```

But no luck, please help!

Thanks

Comment: yes you can... no need to take our permission to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [**STR_TO_DATE**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function

Try this:

If the date format is `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss:sss` then

```
UPDATE mytable SET updated_on = STR_TO_DATE(updated_on, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i:%s');
```

If the date format is `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss:sss` then

```
UPDATE mytable SET updated_on = STR_TO_DATE(updated_on, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s');
```

Comment: i already tried this before posting the question.. and it doesnt work.. the function returns a NULL value causing all records to went all null

Comment: @JasonD I had tried, It was working. Can you explain in which case query update the record to `NULL`

Comment: this string example '23/09/2013 17:30:26:899' in particular returns a NULL value

Comment: @JasonD This date has different format that the format you had specified. You had given the format earlier was `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.sss` and now you are giving the format as `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss.sss`. Please be clear that in which format the dates were stored in table. Give me the actual format of `updated_on` column

Comment: these are the first 10 example of the datas:

'25/09/2013 14:30:26:995',
'01/02/2013 08:30:45:958',
'23/09/2013 13:30:26:744',
'25/03/2013 10:30:24:123',
'30/08/2013 19:30:25:813',
'01/09/2013 14:30:25:847',
'22/09/2013 11:30:28:064',
'01/02/2013 08:30:45:958',
'01/05/2013 21:30:24:728',
'05/09/2013 17:30:25:024'

please notice that the microseconds are with : and not .

Comment: @JasonD As per me the date stored in table was in this format `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss.sss`. So use my second query to update the records in your table

Comment: @SaharshShah please check closer.. ive been telling you ever since that mine uses a colon ":" and NOT a period "." what i have in my table is something like this 30/08/2013 19:30:25:813 - :813 and NOT .813

Comment: @JasonD Do not worry about micro seconds. It won't calculated by str-to-date() function. Try to run the query it will work.

Answer (score 2):

You need proper symbol to represent `microsecond`. It is `%f`.

```
mysql> select str_to_date( '05/11/2009 16:07:53:052', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s:%f' );
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| str_to_date( '05/11/2009 16:07:53:052', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s:%f' ) |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2009-11-05 16:07:53.052000                                       |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

You can omit the time format part just to return date part, but with a warning on data truncation.

```
mysql> select str_to_date( '05/11/2009 16:07:53:052', '%d/%m/%Y' );
+------------------------------------------------------+
| str_to_date( '05/11/2009 16:07:53:052', '%d/%m/%Y' ) |
+------------------------------------------------------+
| 2009-11-05                                           |
+------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                   |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect date value: '05/11/2009 16:07:53:052' |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

***Refer to***:

1. [***MySQL: Date and Time Functions***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html)
2. [***on the same page, a useful reference table on format specifier
   symbols***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Comment: thanks for the tip.. however, what im trying to achieve here is to update the whole table without the miliseconds.. is it possible for you to rewrite the above sql with an update statement? thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is the inverse of the DATE_FORMAT() function. It takes a string str and a format string format. STR_TO_DATE() returns a DATETIME value if the format string contains both date and time parts, or a DATE or TIME value if the string contains only date or time parts. If the date, time, or datetime value extracted from str is illegal, STR_TO_DATE() returns NULL and produces a warning.

The server scans str attempting to match format to it. The format string can contain literal characters and format specifiers beginning with %. Literal characters in format must match literally in str. Format specifiers in format must match a date or time part in str

```
UPDATE mytable SET updated_on = STR_TO_DATE(updated_on, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i:%s')
```

Comment: i just tried it. it works, however not all records was correctly updated.. some other records updated the updated_on field to NULL

Comment: like i said the imported data from the csv contains invalid microseconds value and not nicely formatted.. i think thats the reason why the STR_TO_DATE returns a NULL value when executed.. this string example '23/09/2013 17:30:26:899' in particular returns a NULL value.. is there a way or is it possible to ignore the last part starting from the last semi colon (:899)?